# "She did not report for work" vs. "she did not report to work"

Tags: word-choice, to-for

Which of the two is grammatical or is better in style — "report for work" or "report to work"?

I've always used the first, "report for work", following the pattern of "report for duty", which I always hear law-enforcement folks use.

Answer (score 11):

Both are equally correct. You report *to* (your place of) work in order to report *for* (your assigned) work, so they imply each other and are equivalent in how people use them. Notice that "work" has a different meaning in each phrase (one is a location/building, one is a set of tasks or duties), even though the overall phrases end up having the same meaning.

As an aside, only "report for duty" is correct, since "duty" is not a place that you can report *to*, making *"report to duty" ungrammatical.

Comment: Which do I use if I want to say that someone is absent - She did not (report for) or (report to) work?

Comment: @PrincessNina Again, both are correct. Negating the phrase doesn't change their correctness.

Comment: I agree with your answer, although one _can_ say "[report to duty](http://www.google.com/#q=%22report+to+duty%22&hl=en&prmd=imvns&source=lnms&tbm=bks&sa=X&ei=kdRLUOnfFuS22gXv1ICQBQ&ved=0CA0Q_AUoAA&prmdo=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=1a0c0ef6685e63e7&biw=1303&bih=789)" – it simply means report to the place where you start your duty. (Your overarching point is exactly right, though, either preposition can be used; neither is "more appropriate" than the other.)

Comment: @J.R. I've never heard "report to duty", but then I don't have a military background in the least. I'd be skeptical of it if I did hear it, though. It seems more likely an erroneous application of the "report to work" pattern, like "runned" is a misapplication of the -ed pattern.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: I did spend some time in the military, so perhaps that's why the phrase sounds more "normal" to me, but the usages in the link I provided show plenty of non-military contexts as well; e.g., “Hospital workers’ willingness to report to duty in an influenza pandemic,” “In a company, maintenance persons report to duty at the beginning every 4-hour interval,” “The [post office] employee was being charged with failure to report to duty as assigned,” “[Police] Officer Hewett is scheduled to report to duty at 3 p.m. this afternoon,” and so forth.